# Adding elements to a list of strings in java

Tags: java, string, list

I and more used to how things are done in C# than how things are done in java.  The following lines are in java:

```
List <String> cIDs = null;
cIDs.add("something");
```

This shows a warning in eclipse.  It says that the variable cIDs can only be null at this location.  This tell me that the add will fail.

I tried writing some instantiate code:

```
cIDs = new List<String>()
```

but this does not work in java.

How do I add elements to a list of strings in java?

Comment: `List` is the interface. If you want to instanciate it, you need to use a class that implements the interface, such as `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    ...

    cIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

List is an interface and thus cannot be instantiated.
ArrayList is a concrete class that implements that interface.  Thus is can be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

List is an interface, it is abstract, not to be used to create/instantiate real object. So you have to use its "implementation" either your own:

```
public YourListimplements List<String>{
....
}
List<String> aList = new YourList();
```

( anonymously inline)

```
   List<String> aList= new List<String>() {
   ....
   }
```

or existing one :

```
public class java.util.ArrayList extends java.util.AbstractList implements java.util.List ....{
...
}

List<String> aList= new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface, this means it cannot be instantiated. Instead, use the `ArrayList` implementation:

```
List<String> cIDs = new ArrayList<>();
cIDs.add("something");
```

If the diamond operator (`<>`) isn't supported, use `new ArrayList<String>()`.